# Describing header file locations in makefile

Tags: c++, include, makefile

In a new project I am working on I have the following dir structure:

```
Project_base
|---- src
|---- bin
|---- h
| Makefile
```

And in my source files I have includes that look like so:

```
#include "../h/SomeHeaderFile.h"
```

instead of the more correct form:

```
#include "SomeHeaderFile.h"
```

What do I need to add to my makefile so that I can removed the relative path includes so they will look normal?

---

**ADDITION:** also, where do I set this in CDT (C++ for eclipse) so that in design time this is reflected as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add `-I../h` in the list of parameters you pass to gcc.

Answer (score 2):

Add a flag to your CFLAGS so that the root of the headers is part of the headers search path:

```
-IProject_base/h
```

That way gcc/g++ will also look here in addition to the default headers directories.