# Failing to build xdebug

Tags: php, build, xdebug

I am trying to install xdebug with MAMP on my Mac. I downloaded `xdebug-2.2.1.tgz` and followed the xdebug wizard to run phpize. I ran `make` then I was told of some missing files in `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/include/php/Zend/*`. So, I googled that and I saw I had to download php5.4.4 and then push some files in a new 'include' directory I created in `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/include/php`. But when I try to build again, I have this message :

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/include/php/Zend/zend.h:51:11: fatal error: 
      'zend_config.h' file not found
# include <zend_config.h>
```

What should I do ? Where can I get this file ?

Comment: is it in your `Zend/` dir?

Comment: @iputonmyrobeanwizardhat :  No, in my Zend dir, I have : zend_config.nw.h , zend_config.w32.h

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I finally managed to install xdebug. In fact, I had to install Xcode developer tool and then  copy the files from 
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include/php into /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/include` and then it worked !

Answer (score 0):

Indeed,I thought maybe the make command can not find headers.So I tried to change the makefile:

```
INCLUDES = -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib
```

to

```
INCLUDES = -I{Your Path to php_dir}/php -I{Your Path to php_dir}/php/main -I{Your Path to php_dir}/php/TSRM -I{Your Path to php_dir}/php/Zend -I{Your Path to php_dir}/php/ext -I{Your Path to php_dir}/php/ext/date/lib
```

You may consult this question to change makefile
[Describing header file locations in makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490803/describing-header-file-locations-in-makefile)

You may use this command to find php.h

```
sudo find / -name php.h
```

If you don't have php header,you can install xcode.

After all these,everything is ready now,enjoy!